# Saving multiple android soundboard sounds as either ringtones or notifications using the context menu method

Tags: android, contextmenu

How can I set all of the sounds from a soundboard app I have created as either ringtones or notifications?  I know how to implement the context menu code and register each button for the context menu. What I cannot figure out is how to handle multiple buttons and sounds with only one context menu. I have been through every example on this site and tried all the solutions provided but each response given to similar questions on this site are either too vague or incomplete.

Can somebody please provide me with the solution to my problem without being too vague? I know you don't want to write somebody else's code for them but it would save a lot of newbs like me the countless hours of searching and headache if someone could provided a simple example of the correct code to make this request work. The code below works great but only for the first sound set in the savering and savenot functions. How do I indicate when longpressed that the sound file associated with the button being pressed will be saved as the notification or ringtone?

```
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shesaid);  
    registerForContextMenu(btn); 

    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shesaid2);  
    registerForContextMenu(btn2);

    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shesaid3);  
    registerForContextMenu(btn3);

    Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twss11);  
    registerForContextMenu(btn4);

    Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twss1);  
    registerForContextMenu(btn5);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Save As...");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}
    else {return false;}
return true;
}

public void function1(int id){         
    if (savering(R.raw.shesaid)){              
    // Code if successful              
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    }              
    else              
    {              
    // Code if unsuccessful              
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    }    
}      

public void function2(int id){          
    if (savenot(R.raw.shesaid)){              
    // Code if successful              
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    }              
    else              
    {              
    // Code if unsuccessful              
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            }
    }
```

Above is the context menu code. How can I set it up to use multiple sounds?

```
public boolean savering(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=0;

 try {
  size = fIn.available();
  buffer = new byte[size];
  fIn.read(buffer);
  fIn.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 }

 String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
 String filename="shesaid"+".ogg";

 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

 FileOutputStream save;
 try {
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
  save.write(buffer);
  save.flush();
  save.close();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 }    

 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

 File k = new File(path, filename);

 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "shesaid");
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "nick");
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

 //Insert it into the database
 this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);


 return true;
}

public boolean savenot(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=0;

 try {
  size = fIn.available();
  buffer = new byte[size];
  fIn.read(buffer);
  fIn.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 }

 String path="/sdcard/media/audio/notifications/";
 String filename="shesaid"+".ogg";

 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

 FileOutputStream save;
 try {
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
  save.write(buffer);
  save.flush();
  save.close();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  return false;
 }    

 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

 File k = new File(path, filename);

 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "shesaid");
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "nick");
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

 //Insert it into the database
 this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);


 return true;

}
```

}

Here is the code for each function that saves the sounds to the sdcard. Again, how do I save each sound that is associated with each of the five buttons I have registered context menus for?